# Is Java still king of cross-platform compatibility? Is the answer still Swing?

Tags: java, programming-languages, cross-platform

So basically, my company is looking to create an app that can be distributed on Linux, Mac OS X, and Windows. We are hoping for a cross platform solution. I have experience working with Java Swing years ago and thought it was reasonable, but not great. It assuredly did however work on all platforms just fine. Is Java and Swing still the end all be all of code once run everywhere, or are there other options for desktop apps?

Comment: I thought C was the king of cross-platform compatibility.  I never found Swing a viable solution.

Comment: @RobertHarvey What? If you do C, you have to compile for every single platform and deal with the GUI separately for each platform. There are definitely major applications written in Java (Eclipse, NetBeans, DBVisualizer, etc). I'm just wondering if there is something newer out there at this point.

Comment: There are cross-platform GUI's that are much better than Swing.  Having to compile doesn't make something incompatible.

Comment: If you are familiar with .net languages, you should check out Mono Project: http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page

Comment: @Disa I am not super concerned about what language is used, as I am willing to get involved in anything. thanks for the tip.

Comment: There are *tons* of other options. Cross-platform ported compilers and interpreters have become common place, look at most modern languages, Python, Ruby, JavaScript, Haskell, Perl, C#, F#, there's a compiler and or interpreter for many of them across platforms, things like LLVM and other cross platform VMs people can use for backends have made this pretty common. This question really can't be answered, there's just too many; I only listed a *sliver*, nay a *microbe* of the cross platform languages in modern use today.

Comment: Questions about what language, technology, or project one should take up next are off topic on Programmers, as they can only attract subjective opinions for answers. There are too many individual factors behind the question to create answers that will have lasting value.

Comment: OCaml, Nemerle, SML, ATS, haXe, Mercury, Prolog, SmallTalk, LUA, Erlang, Fantom, Ela, Clojure, Scala, Racket, CLISP, C, C++, J, R, TCL, Oz, ADA, D, Go, Eiffel, and on, and on, and on...

Comment: @thatidiotguy: Stack Exchange is not a recommendation engine.  Recommendation questions are off-topic everywhere.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Well, all the top questions here are completely subjective in my opinion. They are all asking for some advice on a situation. I'm not sure what makes this different.

Comment: @thatidiotguy: Questions and answers need to have a 1:1 relationship for the most part.  Look at the close reason below; it says "There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format."  Subjectiveness only factors in if an excessive amount of it exacerbates the 1:many problem.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Fair enough. Thank you for clarifying. And thank you for the information as well

Comment: @thatidiotguy just for future reference, you can always join the Programmers SE general chat for this type of question; there's often people in there. It's [The Whiteboard](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21/the-whiteboard)

Comment: Since Dec 2013 JavaFX supports iOS and Android. It supported Windows, MacOs and Linux before. But it is different from Swing.

Answer (score 3):

You have basically three practical choices:

1. Java, or a language that runs on the Java platform like Scala or Groovy
2. HTML5, Javascript, CSS3 and Canvas (which will run on pretty much any modern browser),  or
3. [Cross-Platform tools](http://simpleprogrammer.com/2013/07/01/cross-platform-mobile-development/) such as Xamarin and Appcelerator

I would avoid Swing.  It's too labor-intensive, and there are [far better alternatives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_platform-independent_GUI_libraries) out there.

If you're just looking for desktop compatibility, your choices become much broader, as Jimmy Hoffa correctly points out.

Comment: Pfft, there are many more choices, practicality is horribly over-subjective. TCL/tK is still a totally viable way of doing this stuff, as is SmallTalk great for desktop apps and has implementations across platforms.

Comment: On a phone? Sure, you can hack your way into cross-platform nirvana, but why would you want to, especially when the Apple store is involved?  Thanks for the downvote, but my answer still holds; if you want to do this in any sensible way, you will avoid the lemonade stands.

Comment: If he said mobile that's different; but he said desktop app on OSX, Linux, and Windows

Comment: If you're after cross-platform compatibility, why would you exclude phones?  Phones are the gold standard for cross-compatibility problems.

Comment: Desktop UI and Mobile UI require such different designs, it's commonly agreed you create a separate UI for each, I would classify Mobile as a YAGNI if it's nowhere near the initial requirements; chances are if you even try to plan for it you'll end up with mobile requirements that require you to throw most if not all of the desktop app away to write it anyway

Comment: As a side note, Fantom and some other similar languages actually *are* totally viable for this as they compile to .NET or JVM with a shared UI library that is ported to both, and supports mobile as such. Again quibbles like this are why these questions don't work.

Comment: Yeah, but which of these platforms are mainstream enough to be practical choices?  Especially to a pointy-haired boss.  If it's just you writing an open-source application for your own amusement, sure you can use anything you want.

Comment: Why not D? It looks basically like C++

Johannes Pfau has a GDC fork with Android support here:
https://github.com/jpf91/GDC/tree/android

and build scripts that build NDK with D support here:
https://github.com/jpf91/gdc-android-scripts

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/10905376#10905376